# Is it OK for a DNS A record to resolve to another URL rather than an IP address?

Tags: dns

My company use a domain registrar who also offer a web forwarding service.

We have a large number of different domain names purchased over the years and are using this web forwarding service to allow us to forward on requests to old domain names to a suitable location on our main website, as follows:

- User browses to `www.an-old-domain.example`
- `www.an-old-domain.example` resolves via DNS to the IP of our registrar's forwarding server.
- The web forwarding server has been set up to serve an HTTP 302 redirect from `www.an-old-domain.example` to `www.our-corporate-website.example/some-page`
- The user is redirected to `www.our-corporate-website.example/some-page` which in turn resolves via DNS to the IP of our web server

We're having a few problems with the reliability of this redirection service and I was wondering whether it would be OK to create a DNS A record for `www.an-old-domain.example` to resolve to `www.our-corporate-website.example/some-page`, which in turn resolves to the IP address of our web server.

I've always thought that DNS A records should resolve to an IP address rather than a URL, thereby creating a chain of DNS entries. A colleague tells me they that this approach is fine however, but I'm suspicious that it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: An `A` records maps a name to an IPv4 address, never to an URL. So "create a DNS A record for www.an-old-domain.example to resolve to www.our-corporate-website.example/some-page" makes no sense you can just make `www.an-old-domain.example` resolve to the same IP than `www.our-corporate-website.example` and configure this webserver to reply correctly to queries on this name, redirecting them as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using the old domains you should be using a `301` permanent redirect not a 302 temporary (The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI), you're losing link juice using 302's.

One solution is to setup a shared hosting account on hostmonster or another unlimited hosting provider. Have all your old domains use an `.htaccess` file to do the 301 to the specific path on your new domain.

Or take a look at the redirect hard link option from dnsmadeeasy http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/record-entry/http-redirection/

Amazons Route 53 is pretty nice as well and very cheap compared to most other DNS management services.

There's also a few suggestions on redirecting DNS to a file on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507640/using-dns-to-point-a-domain-to-a-specific-page

Nothing fancy though you'll get the same redirect with the .htacess method.